# Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException - There is no column with name 'brand_id' on table 'clients'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm setting up a Symfony2 app and am trying to use Doctrine migrations. In this specific instance, I'm trying to add a new table, clients, for an entity, client, that I just created. This table does not exist in any form right now in the database.

When I run php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff, I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                       
There is no column with name 'brand_id' on table 'clients'
```

Of course there is no column with that name, the table doesn't exist yet!

Shouldn't Doctrine recognize that there is no table and create it? For reference, here's my entity:

```
<?php

namespace RandomBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="brand_id", columns={"brand_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \RandomBundle\Entity\Brand
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RandomBundle\Entity\Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @var \RandomBundle\Entity\Project
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RandomBundle\Entity\Project", mappedBy="client")
     */
    private $projects;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $updatedAt;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set brand
     *
     * @param \Ripplr3\RipplrBundle\Entity\Brand $brand
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setBrand(\RandomBundle\Entity\Brand $brand = null)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brand
     *
     * @return \RandomBundle\Entity\Brand 
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    /**
     * Add projects
     *
     * @param \RandomBundle\Entity\Project $projects
     * @return Client
     */
    public function addProject(\RandomBundle\Entity\Project $projects)
    {
        $this->projects[] = $projects;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove projects
     *
     * @param \RandomBundle\Entity\Project $projects
     */
    public function removeProject(\RandomBundle\Entity\Project $projects)
    {
        $this->projects->removeElement($projects);
    }

    /**
     * Get projects
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar error which was caused by ```/*```. It means multiline comment started with ```/*``` instead of ```/**```.

Answer (score 5):

The unique point that i can see is the indexes declaration

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="brand_id", columns={"brand_id"})})
```

i don't know if it's trying to create an index before create the table..
try delete it to see if the problem persists

Comment: i think you're doing on the right way.. 
`/**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/` (http://goo.gl/UipasD)

Comment: Worked for me. Indexes where messing up the shema but where not detected by shema:validate